# mongo native not creating data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

Im trying to create data if a facebook id exists in the database else create new data, however the first condition works fine but when its creating data nothing happens, ony get `connot read property 'provider' of null` even i hard code a provider value.

```
db.collection('accounts', function(err, collection){
    collection.findOne({'email': fbEmail}, function(err, item){
        var providerId = item.provider.facebook.id;
        console.log("facebook id should be: "+providerId);
        if(providerId == ""){
            collection.update({email:fbEmail, 'provider.facebook.id':""}, {$set: {"provider.facebook.id": fbId}}, {safe:true}, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log("id updated!");
                };
            });
        }else{ //creates a new user
            console.log("creating a new account...");
            collection.update({'email': fbEmail}, {
                'email': fbEmail,
                'provider':
                    {
                        'facebook': {'id': fbId},                            
                        'twitter': {'id': ""}                                
                    }                    
            }, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error finding email "+err);
                }                
            });             
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In your `findOne` callback you need to check if `item` is `null` or not before checking `item.provider`.  `item` will be `null` if this is a new email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (the first one) of `accounts` collection documents has `provider=null`. You can modify `findOne` condition the following way to avoid it:

```
collection.findOne({'email': fbEmail, 'provider': {$exists: true}}, ...
```

Note, that this modification will just skip all accounts without `provider` field set (or with set to `null`).

Comment: sorry if im not fully understand your note, i still need to perform the first `collection.update` when facebook id in the provider is `null`, but if i skip all accounts without `provider` field set then Im not sure how to perform the above action again.

Comment: I think i solved it =) just place the create new email outside the `findOne` and use `{$exists: true}` as you said, thank you!

Comment: My intention with the note was to warn you about the case when no provider is given. Anyway I'm happy you've solved the problem. You're welcome!

Comment: actually there is still a problem, i still need to create new data if the email doesnt exist, looking at the mongodb query doc...

Comment: In this case I'm usually fetching account (`findOne`) (if it exists), then processing or creating retrieved object and finally saving (`save(usert=true)`) it.

Comment: yes i have the workflow in the head, just the queries are confusing me